# Backbone Collections - is create() an instance method?

Tags: javascript, oop, backbone.js

I have a collection of Backbone models like so:

```
window.Message = Backbone.Model.extend({});

window.MessageCollect = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: Message, url: '/messages'});
```

Why do I have to instantiate a new collection in order to call create()?  If I call create() on MessageCollect, I get a no method error.

```
window.Messages = new MessageCollect;

function makeMessage(){ Messages.create({title:'first message', sender:user_name}); }
//ok

function makeMessageTwo(){ MessageCollect.create({title:'first message', sender:user_name}); }
//Object function (){ parent.apply(this, arguments); } has no method 'create'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Backbone.Collection - is a class, not an instance. When you call Backbone.Collection.extend you extend base class, you do not create new instance.
Collection.create() - method to create new model in collection INSTANCE. When you don't have instance, how can you append new models into it?

Answer (score 2):

To better understand what's happening here, [here is what _.extend does](http://underscorejs.org/#extend):

> Copy all of the properties in the source objects over to the
>   destination object, and return the destination object. It's in-order,
>   so the last source will override properties of the same name in
>   previous arguments.

so Backbone.Collection.extend is just taking the source object that you defined and adding its properties to Backbone.Collection so that it augments with what you defined and then assign it to your variable window.MessageCollect.

Looking at [backbone code](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/backbone.html), what it does is that it "extends" the **prototype** of Collection with these methods Create, Add, toJson etc... since it added to the prototype then it applies to **instances** of the Backbone.Collection not the function itself, because this is [what prototype does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/prototype)

> Function objects inherit from Function.prototype. Modifications to the
>   Function.prototype object are propagated to all Function instances.

In a way, it is equivalent to this simple code:

```
var Car = function(name){
    this.name = name;
}

var ford = new Car("ford");

Car.prototype.drive = function(){
    console.log("drive");
}

ford.drive(); //possible
Car.drive(); // not possible: Uncaught TypeError: object has no method 'drive'
​
```

​